# How do I remove moss from patio?

Tags: moss, patio

I have a stone patio outside my back door, built with (approx.) 12"x12" pavers. Each spring, moss grows up through the cracks between the bricks. I have scraped it off and dug it out as best I could each time, but it grows back every year, sometimes even before the summer is over.

Is there a way to prevent this from growing back?

Comment: Hi DLev, it's nice to meet you! I found [this](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4933/how-do-i-control-weeds-and-moss-on-a-brick-walkway-and-driveway) question, which appears similar to yours. I encourage you to check it out, in case some of the answers there might help you. If not, perhaps you could post a picture so people can see exactly what you're dealing with. We hope to see more of you here at GL!

Comment: Thanks Sue! Just thought of posting this question here this morning (I typically use Graphic Design Stack). I was going to take a picture this weekend and post it. :) I'll check out the link you provided too!

Comment: Hi again! This came up to be marked as a duplicate. I imagine you know how it works from Graphic Design. We just want to make sure all the detailed information stays in the same place. If you feel there's something significantly different about your question, feel free to edit it to let us know what that is. If you have other gardening questions, we look forward to seeing them.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, but you can use a product specifically designed for use on hard surfaces such as Patio Magic, which does have some residual deterrent effect. Use as instructed on the container. I imagine your paving is in a fairly shady area, which encourages moss and the like, particularly through winter when the air is damp. You'll likely have to use the product at least once a year.

Some people, though, allow the moss to remain, and even try to encourage its growth, considering it attractive.

Comment: Thanks Bamboo. It is in fact in a more shady area for most of the day/year. I'll check into the product you mentioned.